# Why doesn't getchar stop to get input?

Tags: c, input, scanf, user-input, getchar

I have the following piece of code which is supposed to interact with the user as to what he wants to do.

```
int input;
printf("Would you like to update the name of the student?\n");
printf("Enter Y(yes) or N(no)\n");
input = getchar();

if (input == 'Y' || input == 'y') {
  printf("Please enter the updated name\n");
  scanf("%s", tmpSt->name);
}

printf("Would you like to update the student's ID?\n");
printf("Enter Y(yes) or N(no)\n");
input = getchar();
```

But when executed it doesn't stop to get the first input.

```
Would you like to update the name of the student?
Enter Y(yes) or N(no)
Would you like to update the student's ID?
Enter Y(yes) or N(no)
```

It is supposed to get an answer for the name but it goes straight to the id.

Comment: I suspect there may be something in the input buffer (maybe a trailing newline from a previous input), which `getchar` picks up. Try printing `input` and see what the value is.

Comment: I printed ```input``` and it prints a newline

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`scanf("%s", ...)` leaves the newline entered by the user pending in the input stream.

Instead of `getchar()`, use `char c; scanf(" %c", &c);` The initial space will make `scanf()` ignore pending whitespace, including the pending newline.

Also check the return value of `scanf()` to detect invalid input and end  of file.

Comment: I've tried it with scanf but it does the same thing :(

Comment: @SpyrosMouchlianitis:  Make sure you have space at the beginning of the `" %c"` format string.